# Express.js req.session is undefined in route

Tags: node.js, session, express, undefined

I genrated Express app from scratch and add cookieParser, session and csrf middlewares

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: "lalala" }));
app.use(express.csrf());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(80, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Then in index router I tried to have access to the session

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.cookie('u','1');
  console.log(res.session);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

but unfortunatelly it's always undefined!
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking on the response (`res`) instead of the request (`req`). `console.log(req.session)` should work. Easy mistake to make.